# ui text field updating SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, text, sprite-kit, field

I am working on a code to allow a user to update a SKLabelNode by minuting text into a UI text field as below. 
I would ideally like the text to be updated as they type, one letter at a time. But I am a bit stuck as to how to do this?
At the moment I just have another button "labelNode2" which updates the text when pressed.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, UITextFieldDelegate {

    private var field : UITextField?
    lazy var labelNode = self.childNode(withName: "labelNode") as? SKLabelNode
    lazy var labelNode2 = self.childNode(withName: "labelNode2") as? SKLabelNode

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        labelNode?.text = "Test"  
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches  {

            let largeLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            let nodes = self.nodes(at: largeLocation)
            for node in nodes {
                if node.name == "labelNode" {

                    labelNode?.text = "hello"
                    if (field == nil) {
                        field = UITextField()
                        field?.frame = CGRect(x:100,y:100, width:100, height:30)
                        field?.delegate = self;
                        field?.backgroundColor = .red
                        field?.isHidden = true;
                        self.view?.addSubview(field!)
                    }

                    field?.text = labelNode?.text

                    field?.becomeFirstResponder
                }
                else {
                    field?.resignFirstResponder
                    //To hide keyboard
                }
                if node.name == "labelNode2" {
                   labelNode?.text = field?.text
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I had to comment out your line `field.isHidden = true`.

Second of all, there are no semicolons in swift.

And finally...  add this and you should be fine...

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //labelNode?.text = field?.text
    labelNode?.text = (field?.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return true
}
```

Why did I comment out that first line? Because the text change does not take effect until you return true...

Comment: thats great thanks, it does work.... I am just trying to get my head around how. So is it because there is a TexField delegate that the function gets called each time any UItext field is active?. So could I now apply this to multiple input fields with the same function.

Comment: Well, in your function you SET the delegate to be Game Scene.  That means any times something happens to the text field, that delegate function will be called.  ANY text field whose delegate is the object will call that objects delegate function.  There is also a "TextFieldDidBecomeActive" function that would be called when you activate a text field.

Comment: ok thanks, I've had a play with it and now have a single UITextField and several labels. Each time a label is clicked it changes the tag of the textfield (which is read in the function). This allows each lable to be edited independently through the single textfield.